# Time Trigger for existing records

Tags: workflow

I have created a time trigger workflow to notify campaign owners (few listed users) once the campaign is ended after 1 day and final notification after 3 days.

- This is the workflow condition :
- created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria

Workflow formula :

```
 AND( 
 OR ( 
 (OwnerId = '0050K000008w8dA'), 
 (OwnerId = '00528000003hxZN')), 
 EndDate = Today()    
 )
```

- Then created time trigger: `1 - Days - After - Campaign: EndDate`
- One more time trigger created for 3 days final notification.
- Then Workflow Action - New Email Alert - Added the template and selected  Owner in the Recipient Type.

I created a test campaign with End date today and checked the time-based workflow under Monitor and when I search with the workflow name it's showing up the Scheduled notification time.

My concern is :

- Will the existing campaign trigger if the end date reaches today, without a campaign being edited? If no, can you please suggest a solution for this scenario?
- There is a time lag between countries, how will the notification go if the time zone is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 AND( 
 OR ( 
 (OwnerId = '0050K000008w8dA'), 
 (OwnerId = '00528000003hxZN')), 
 EndDate = Today()    
 )
```

Based on your stated objective, you do not need (and shouldn't include) `EndDate` in your workflow entry criteria. You don't need this to use time-based actions. It sounds like you probably just want

```
 OR ( 
 (OwnerId = '0050K000008w8dA'), 
 (OwnerId = '00528000003hxZN'))
```

> Will the existing campaign trigger if the end date reaches today, without a campaign being edited? If no, can you please suggest a solution for this scenario?

No, it will not. You can export all your existing Campaigns and perform a zero-content update with the data loader (just run an update on a file with no content except the Id) as an easy fix to get the workflow to fire and enqueue its time-dependent actions.

However, as written, your workflow rule won't fire on updates that don't change previously non-matching records to meet your criteria. You may want to change the entry criteria to allow updates *other* than updates to meet criteria to allow workflow entry, perform the updates, and then reset the criteria on the workflow.

> There is a time lag between countries, how will the notification go if the time zone is different?

Per [Considerations for Time-Dependent Actions and Time Triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=5),

> Salesforce evaluates time-based workflow on the organization’s time zone, not the user’s. Users in different time zones might see differences in behavior.

Comment: David and SFDCfox,  Perfect!!, Sorry for the delayed response, I updated the all the records and tested it again, it worked !!

Answer (score 1):

> -Will the existing campaign trigger if the end date reaches today, without a campaign being edited? If no, can you please suggest a solution for this scenario?

No. You would need to edit/update all existing records in order to get the records queued. Workflow rules are not applied retroactively.

> There is a time lag between countries, how will the notification go if the time zone is different?

The workflow rule should work correctly; the calculated values are in GMT. They'll get the notification at the correct time.